# ¿Cómo usar React con Babel 6 sin recibir error de 'keys' indefinidas?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, babel

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de React y me encontré con un problema en el primer ejemplo que he probado: importo la versión más moderna de React y del paquete React Dom, también importo la última versión de Babel (para usar JSX) y creo una pequeña versión del Hola Mundo:

```html
<div id="title"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>, 
  document.querySelector("#title") 
);
</script>
```

Pero al ejecutar, falla; aparece el siguiente error en `browser.min.js` y no funciona nada:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined

Mirando en Internet, vi que esto se debe a cambios en el core de la versión de Babel (6.x), y se puede solucionar utilizando una versión antigua (por ejemplo la 5.8.24):

```html
<div id="title"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>, 
  document.querySelector("#title") 
);
</script>
```

Ahora mi pregunta es: ¿se puede usar React con Babel 6? ¿Cómo sería?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede a la perfección y usar la versión 6 no supone inconveniente alguno. Cuando se desarrolla con [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) a menudo se necesita un **bundler**. Un bundler no es más que un programa que *transpila* código ES6+ con diferentes variantes como JSX a ES5.

El stack que necesitas para tener corriendo React y ES6+ a la perfección es:

- [Webpack](https://webpackjs.org) u otros como [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com).
- React y React DOM.
- Babel: core, loader y presets. Si usas ciertas características como async/await u object spread necesitarás **transformadores** y babel-polyfill.

---

**1. Dependencias**

Las dependencias básicas para desarrollo son las siguientes:

> **Nota:** las dependencias de desarrollo deben instalarse con `--save-dev` o `-D`.

- `babel-core`: núcleo de babel, utilitarios, etc.
- `babel-loader`: loader usado para transpilar
- `babel-preset-es2015`: preset para ES6
- `babel-preset-react`: preset para react (JSX)
- `es6-promise`: polyfill para ES6 Promise
- `whatwg-fetch`: polyfill para la Fetch API
- `imports-loader`: polyfill para import (webpack)
- `exports-loader`: polyfill para export (webpack)

React y ReactDOM deben instalarse como dependencias runtime, es decir, con el parámetro `--save` o `-S`.

> **Nota:** es importante que instales webpack tanto como dependencia de desarrollo (`-D`) como global (`-g`).

**2. Archivo de configuración babel**

Los bundles buscarán el archivo de configuración de babel y, de no encontrarlo, solicitará que se pase la configuración *inline*. El archivo de babel se llama `.babelrc` y dentro tiene los presets y plugins que uses:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015", "react"
  ]
}
```

**3. Configuración de Webpack**

Webpack require un archivo llamado `webpack.config.js` para poder llevar a cabo su tarea. Este archivo contiene la configuración para el proceso de transpilación y operaciones posteriores como es el caso de *minificar*, *concatenar* archivos, agregar prefijos automáticamente a las hojas de estilo, etc.

La configuración básica de Webpack para React y ES6 se ve así:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const { join, resolve } = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    // archivo principal, no es obligatoria esta ruta
    // debes poner la ruta de tu archivo principal
    bundle: './src/ui/Main.jsx',
  },
  output: {
    // directorio de salida
    path: join(__dirname, './public'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.js(x)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }, // end module
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      resolve('/'),
      'node_modules/',
    ],
    // extensiones que serán resueltas por webpack
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    unsafeCache: true,
  },
  // aquí van los puglins de webpack.
  plugins: [
    // Estos plugins importan/exportan librerías
    // dentro del objeto global window
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Promise: 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.Promise!es6-promise',
      fetch: 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
    }),
    // descomentar si se está en producción
    // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  stats: { colors: true },
}
```

Los puntos más importantes en Webpack son:

- entry: aquí se especifica el archivo principal del front. En este archivo se requerirán el resto de la aplicación.
- output: aquí se especifica el directorio de salida y el nombre (opcional) del archivo generado.
- rules: aquí van las *reglas* que interpretará Webpack; se le pasa una extensión en expresión regular y un loader. Cuando Webpack encuentre un archivo con esa extensión, aplicará el loader que queramos, en este caso, babel.
- extensions: aquí van las extensiones que serán *reconocidas* por Webpack. Si pones `.jsx` ya no es necesario importar un archivo como `import Module form 'Module.jsx'`, se puede omitir la extensión.

Finalmente solo debes ejecutar:

```
webpack --watch
```

O si configuraste el script `build` del `package.json`:

```
npm run build
```

Y webpack empezará a hacer su trabajo; en la consola aparecerá información del proceso y escuchará cualquier cambio en el código fuente para proceder a realizar una y otra vez el proceso. En el HTML solo debes anexar el bundle generado para tener tu aplicación funcional:

```
<script defer src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Para no hacerla más larga xD, si quieres usar ES7 y 8 necesitarás instalar esos presets; además, ES8 incorpora funciones asíncronas (aka async/await), así que necesitarás el plugin [babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator](https://npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator) y debes ponerlo en el `.babelrc` dentro de *plugins*: `"plugins": ["transform-async-to-generator"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente lo solucioné utilizando la versión *standalone* de Babel 6. Ésta incluye el core (núcleo) de Babel y algunas dependencias que hacen que funcione con React para lo que estoy haciendo ahora mismo:

```html
<div id="title"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>, 
  document.querySelector("#title") 
);
</script>
```